# file opened with popen() has no EOF?

Tags: c

i want to write to content of the directory into a buffer  but i always get 
"dir to large for buffer"     ...and i have no idea why   the directory is max 3000 chars long

it also doest work with  '\n' instead of EOF

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv){
   FILE* fp;
   fp=popen("ls /etc","r");
   char c;
   int i=0;
   char buffer[20000];
   while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
      buffer[i]=c;
      i++;
      if(i=20000){
         printf("dir to large for buffer");
         break;
      }
   }
   buffer[i]='\0';
}
```

Comment: `i=20000` --> `i==20000-1`. Also `char c;` --> `int c;`

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really indent your code. BTW indentation is not to please your teacher but it's for you (and also for us) so you/we can read your program,

Answer (score 3):

[Per the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html), `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.

`char c;`

is wrong.  It should be

`int c;`

And, as noted:

`if (i=20000) ...`

will always evaluate to true.  It should be

`if (i==(20000 - 1)) ...`

given you're apparently trying to create a `'\0'`-terminated C string.

Comment: And also, `i=20000` should be `i==20000`.

Comment: True, but not the only problem.